# How do I link object on the XAML side in a ContentView?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make a template to centralize the display of a product.

I succeeded with **x:Name** but I'd like to do this binding on the XAML side like for a page.

Why isn't this working?

**MainPage.cs**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<base:PageBase
    x:Class="MobileApp.Pages.Main.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:main="clr-namespace:MobileApp.Pages.Main"
    xmlns:templates="clr-namespace:MobileApp.Pages.Templates"
    x:DataType="main:MainPageViewModel">
    <StackLayout Padding="10">
        <StackLayout>
            <templates:ProductTemplate Product="{Binding SelectedProduct}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</base:PageBase>
```

**ProductTemplate.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="MobileApp.Pages.Templates.ProductTemplate"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Product.Code}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Product.Name}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**ProductTemplate.xaml.cs**

```cs
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ProductTemplate : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ProductProperty = BindableProperty
        .Create(nameof(Product),
        typeof(Product),
        typeof(ProductTemplate),
        default(Product));

    public Product Product
    {
        get => GetValue(ProductProperty) as Product;
        set => SetValue(ProductProperty, value);
    }

    public ProductTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the binding path in xaml of Custom View .

#### ProductTemplate.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
              x:Name="CustomView"  // set the name of view
             x:Class="App18.ProductTemplate">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="{Binding Product.Code,Source={x:Reference CustomView}}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Product.Name,Source={x:Reference CustomView}}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

#### ProductTemplate.xaml.cs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ProductTemplate : ContentView, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ProductTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ProductProperty = BindableProperty
    .Create(nameof(Product),
    typeof(Product),
    typeof(ProductTemplate),
    default(Product),
    propertyChanged: (obj,oldValue,newValue) =>{


        var bindableObj = obj as ProductTemplate;

        bindableObj.Product = newValue as Product;

    });

    Product product;
    public Product Product
    {
        get {

            return product;
          
        }

        set
        {
            if(product != value)
            {
                product = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Product");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### in MainPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

    <local:ProductTemplate WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="400" BackgroundColor="LightPink" Product="{Binding xxx}"/>
      
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the `BindingContext` in Xamarin forms

So I think this would already give you results:

```
this.BindingContext = this;
```

But don't do this please. Wrap your `Product` in another model or set the `BindingContext` to `Product` and bind to `Code` and `Name` directly:

this.BindingContext = this.Product;

and bind:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Code}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: None of the solutions work. Also, I think you lose the binding if you change property.